# Checking if Employee ID is present for approval of registration

Tags: mysql, assets

I'm trying to figure out a stored procedure on checking the input of employee id if it is present in the database already. If it is present then there will be an insert of his/her personal information. 
Here's my code: I badly need a solution! I'm not that expert at SQL queries.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `register`(

        IN  EmployeeID INT(11), 
        IN  GivenName VARCHAR(20), 
        IN  MI VARCHAR(10), 
        IN  Surname VARCHAR(20), 
        IN  Gender VARCHAR(6),
        IN  month VARCHAR(2),
        IN  day VARCHAR(2),
        IN  year VARCHAR(4),
        IN  Landline INT(8),
        IN  Cellphone BIGINT(20),
        IN  EMail VARCHAR(30))


BEGIN

SELECT emp_id FROM `assettracker`.`employee`;

IF (empid=EmployeeID) THEN

INSERT INTO `assettracker`.`employee` (emp_fname, emp_midname, emp_surname, emp_gender, 
emp_bday,emp_phone, emp_cellphone, emp_email) 
                    VALUES(GivenName, MI, Surname, Gender, CONCAT(month,'/',day,'/',year), 
                                        Landline, Cellphone, EMail);

ENDIF;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Add where clause while selecting `emp_id`.

```
IF not EXISTS (SELECT emp_id FROM `assettracker`.`employee` Where emp_id=EmployeeID) Then
    //insert statement
END IF;
```

Comment: It worked with no errors! but there were 0 rows affected.

Here's the call statement:
call assettracker.register(30001, 'Phoebe', 'C', 'Gojocco', 'Female', 08, 20, 1993, 654324, 09166394754, 'phoebe.gojocco@gmail.com')

Comment: The employee table has already employee numbers saved in it. The query must check if the data input is present in the table.

Comment: Then remove **not**. Just use IF EXISTS syntax.